Проблемы с подключением к удаленному рабочему столу
В какой-то момент перестало подключаться к удаленному рабочему столу. Ввожу ip, имя пользователя, пароль, после чего бесконечный синий экран с надписью "Подождите". В сведениях о подключении пишет: "высокое время кругового пути подключения и, возможно, низкая скорость сети". Но при этом раньше проблем с этим не было.
windows 11 home

Ты К win11 хочешь подключиться? Или С него? А на той стороне что и где?
